# Data attribute in object tag causes an error with print

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I have an object tag as the following below :

```
MyPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
     " <object id = 'Obj' name='MyPdf' type='application/pdf' 
               width='500' height='500'>
       <param name='SRC'  value='pdfshow.aspx' /></object> "));
```

When I'm trying to print the embeded `pdf` within the object, it works fine

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(),"Message", 
    "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>document.MyPdf.printWithDialog();</script>", false);
```

But I need to add data attribute to the object,

```
MyPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
      " <object id = 'Obj' name='MyPdf' 
                type='application/pdf' width='500' height='500' data='pdfshow.aspx'>
        <param name='SRC'  value='pdfshow.aspx' /></object> "));
```

When I add data , it gives me an error that no function called `printWithDialog()` to MyPdf.

Answer (score 1):

Shoud be :

```
<object data='pdfshow.aspx' id = 'Obj' name='MyPdf' type='application/pdf' width...>
____________^
```

Instead of :

```
<object data=value='pdfshow.aspx' id = 'Obj' name='MyPdf' type='application/pdf' width...>
____________^^^^^^
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please note that There is typing error , I meant data='pdfshow.aspx' instead of data=value='pdfshow.aspx'

Comment: Sorry I can not see difference between your answer and mine, I've tried data='Pdfshow.aspx' as I stated in the question.